# curl of what yields $(0,s^{-1},0)$ in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

In cylindrical coordinates $(s,\theta,z)$, what function $\mathbf{A}$ has the property $$\nabla\times \mathbf{A} = (0, \frac{1}{s} , 0) $$

I know generally that $$\nabla\times \mathbf{A} = \left(\frac{1}{s}\frac{\partial A_3}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial z}, \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_3}{\partial s} , \frac{1}{s} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(s\cdot A_2) - \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial \theta}\right)\right) $$

Is there some better way of solving for $\mathbf{A}$ other than a *lot* of ugly equations?

Comment: Do you know anything about the function $A$?  Perhaps it should have zero divergence?

Comment: @Muphrid Yes, I didn't mention it but $\vec\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$. $\mathbf{A}$ is a magnetic vector potential.

Comment: @BBB Not only $A$ is divergence free, $\nabla \times A$ has to be divergence free too, perhaps $1/s$ is in the third component.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use a Green's function to solve this PDE.

The relevant Green's function is

$$\mathbf G(\mathbf r) = \frac{\mathbf r}{4\pi r^3}$$

The function $\mathbf A$ can then be found by convolution with the Green's function.  Let $\mathbf B = s^{-1} \hat \theta$.  The solution is then

$$\mathbf A(\mathbf r) = \int_{M} \mathbf B(\mathbf r') \times \mathbf G(\mathbf r - \mathbf r') \, dV'$$

*Edit*: there was a surface integral here, but I realized I had it written down wrong. I'll have to find a source for this, for while the volume integral is pretty simple, the surface integral looks, to me, to be a bit complicated, and you probably don't want to do that.  I'll try to verify the form of that integral.  Choosing all space as your integration region safely ignores the surface integral, but you may not be able to do this easily with $1/s$ in your vector field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a path integral formula to construct the inverse of the exterior derivative operator for closed differential forms, for curl in three dimensions:
$$
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}\newcommand{\ps}{\boldsymbol{\psi}} \newcommand{\p}{\mathbf{p}} \mathscr{R}(\ps) = -(\p - \p_0)\times \int^1_0 \ps\big(\p_0 + t(\p- \p_0)\big)t\,dt,\tag{1}
$$
where $\p = (x,y,z)$ and $\ps$ has to be *divergence free*. We have that $\mathscr{R}(\ps) $ satisfies:
$$
\nabla \times \mathscr{R}(\ps) = \ps.
$$

---

The vector field you gave, $(0,1/s,0) = (0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0)$, is not divergence free, there does not exist any vector potential $\A$ satisfying:
$$
\nabla \times \A = (0,\frac{1}{s},0). 
$$
However, we can just modify a little bit to make your question a well-posed problem, we can move $1/s$ to the $z$-component, and it is divergence free:
$$
\nabla \cdot \left(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) = 0,
$$
and 
$$
\nabla \times \A = (0,0,\frac{1}{s})
$$
has a solution (not unique though).

---

Let $\ps$ be the above vector, and in (1) we take $\p_0$ as the origin we have:
\begin{align}
\A = &\mathscr{R}(\ps) = -\p\times \int^1_0 \ps(t\p)t\,dt
\\
&= -(x,y,z)\times \left(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)
\\
&=  \left(-\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0\right).\tag{2}
\end{align}

We can check:
\begin{align}
\nabla \times\A &= \left(0,0, \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big) + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\Big)\right)
\\
&= \left(0,0, \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - x\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - y\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2}\right)
\\
& = \left(0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right).
\end{align}

Or you can rewrite (2) in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\A = (-\sin\theta, \cos\theta,0),
$$
and use the curl formula you gave.

Comment: According to the divergence operator in cylindrical coordinates, your original statement doesn't look right and should be divergenceless, since the operator in cylindrical coordinates is $$ \nabla \cdot \vec{A} = \frac{1}{s} \frac{ \partial }{\partial s} (s A_1) + \frac{1}{s} \frac{ \partial }{\partial \theta} (A_2) + \frac{ \partial }{\partial z} (A_3) $$ and the second component doesn't depend on theta, although I agree that I don't know if it was written correctly.

Comment: @Dan Okay, I see. The vector field is given in basis of $(s,\theta,z)$. But in that case, $s=0$? I will modify my answer later if OP edit his question.

Comment: No problem. I always hate these problems of going backwards from $\vec{B}$ to $\vec{A}$